# Error chromedriver executable need s to be in PATH while running python selenium based test case on CentOS

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, centos7, google-chrome-headless

I am getting error on CentOS while running python selenium based test cases. How can I overcome this issue?

Error is :

```
 Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I am using below code in my main python file.

```
    self.options = Options()
    self.options.set_headless(headless=True)
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options, executable_path='./chromedriver')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try giving full path with `.exe`:

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options, executable_path='./chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: This is what I am getting with .exe :  'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Can you please try with full exe path once and see if the error remains the same? Also, please try `sudo chmod 777 chromedriver.exe` by going to that folder.

Comment: You mean like this?                     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=self.options, executable_path='sudo chmod 777 chromedriver.exe')

Comment: No. Go to your folder where you have your `chromedriver.exe` in a console and run command `sudo chmod 777 chromedriver.exe`. Then try running again with same configuration that I mentioned above with `.exe` path.

Comment: You are in centos. Right? We are trying to change the file permissions first and then see if it runs.

Comment: Yes centos.   applying above mentioned instructions, I am getting another issue :  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
OSError: [Errno 8] Exec format error: './chromedriver.exe'

Comment: There is some issue with the path .Try with complete path of chromedriver.exe  instead of relative path. like `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver`

Comment: What did `chmod` returned you? Were you able to execute it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174445/discussion-between-edupeeth-and-user3157061).